# What is the HTTP content type for binary plist?

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, plist, mime-types

I am modifying a rails server to handle binary plist from an iPhone client via POST and PUT requests.  The content type for text plist is text/plist, as far as I can tell.  I would like the server to handle both text and binary plists, so I would like to distinguish between the two forms.  What is the content type for binary plist?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe that most binary formats are preceded by `application` so maybe `application/plist`.

See the bottom of [RFC1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html).

**Update**

Like Pumbaa80 mentioned, since `application/plist` is not a standard mime-type it should be `application/x-plist`.

In RFC2045 it explains this:

> In the future, more top-level types
>      may be defined only by a standards-track extension to this standard.
>      If another top-level type is to be used for any reason, it must be
>      given a name starting with "X-" to indicate its non-standard status
>      and to avoid a potential conflict with a future official name.

Comment: That's good, that was my semi-educated guess.  So it must be right.  :-)  I'll accept your answer unless someone else has a better suggestion.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: There [is no](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/) application/plist MIME-Type. Use application/x-plist instead.